# What is the best place to save logged in user object in Angular 5

Tags: angular, local-storage, angular5

when the user first logs into the system it should be kept in some sort of cache (localStorage, sessionStorage, cookie) so that even when the page is reloaded, the user details will be there to be used in the application.

I want to know what is the best place to store those details because in my user object there is quiet lot data to be stored and currently i'm using localStorage and stringifying the user object in there

this is what I have now

```
localStorage.setItem("accessToken", loginResponse.access_token);
localStorage.setItem("refreshToken", loginResponse.refresh_token);
localStorage.setItem("expiresIn", loginResponse.expires_in);
localStorage.setItem("userObject", JSON.stringify(loginResponse.data));
```

And also when the view is required to display the user image and name Im thinking to get the required userObject from localStorage and save it in a service variable so that I don't need to parse the JSON everywhere I use it.

Any ideas of how to retain quiet big JSON objects in Angular 5 when page refreshes or any Angular 5 packages/component that lets me store them as JSON rather than a string

Comment: You can use local storage itself to store big JSON objects

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to persist the data for refresh and user session, then you can also use `sessionStorage`.

If you want to persist it till token expires, then your current approach of using `localstorage` looks fine.